# Game Center between full and lite version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gamekit, game-center

Is this possible? I want to implement multiplayer in my game using Game Center Matchmaking, but is it possible to let owners of the full version play against owners of the lite version? I couldn't find a clear answer in the Apple docs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apps will find each other only if they share the same Bundle ID.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works- and it well might, I am not an iPhone developer, just an iPad user- you could try going with only one version of your application, with the Pro version existing as an in-app upgrade.

Comment: If the app hasn't shipped yet, I think this is the way to go. If you already have two versions in the store, however...

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to establish local or peer-to-peer connections between applications with different bundle ids (such as full versus lite versions, or iPhone versus iPad versions). As long as all your apps use the same session id for their GKSession objects, you should be fine.

For instance, I've been able to play with NOVA for iPad against two other players using NOVA for iPhone in a peer-to-peer match.